Issue with Time Configuration in xlreporter
I'm experiencing issues with xlreporter when graphing data from an SQL query. In my SQL query, I select and filter data using the following query:
SELECT PT102_PV, t_stamp FROM group_table WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '2024-07-30 00:00' AND '2024-07-31 00:00' AND PT102_PV IS NOT NULL ORDER BY t_stamp DESC;
In the SQL query, the date and time are displayed correctly. However, when I configure xlreporter to plot PT102_PV based on the date and time from t_stamp, the time is not being interpreted correctly. The date is correct, but the time appears to be incorrect or misinterpreted. I have checked that xlreporter is set to use the date and time from t_stamp, but the issue persists.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve this?
I reviewed the configuration in xlreporter and ensured that the date and time format matches that of my SQL query. I also tried different settings in xlreport to adjust the format of the graph axes and make sure the time is interpreted correctly. However, the time still appears incorrectly on the graphs, while the date is displayed correctly.
I expected xlreporter to correctly interpret both the date and time from t_stamp and for the graph to accurately reflect these data, showing the correct time for each PT102_PV value.
comparative image SQL query and XLreporter query (SQL Correct)
XLReport Configuration

I assume the time zone on your sql server, SSRS server, and client aren't 4 hours apart.

yes, the configuration of sql server, the ssrs server and the client are set to the same time zone.  now, I'm not using ssrs since for reporting because I'm using xlreporter. thanks for your response
